# How to keep an environment variable after program closes

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, environment-variables

I have an application to change the `PATH` environment variable. But every time it changes `PATH`, when the application is open again, the `PATH` seems to be set to the old one.

My code is the following:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable( "PATH" , "%new path%");
```

Comment: There is a windows API function for setting global environment variables. Using it requires administrative privileges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the variable for the whole machine, not just the app. Try this:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable( "PATH" , "%new path%", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```

you do need to be aware of security issues though, setting variable for the machine may require additional privileges. You can also set for the user if required.

Comment: Yeah, I have added a Admin Permission Check, and made some parts of the PATH unremoveable, I'll try this and see if it works.